# Minimize sum of multiplicative inverse functions over a constrain

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I've been stuck with this non-linear optimization problem with non-linear equality constrain for some time now:

$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Minimize} &\quad \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{x_i} \\
\operatorname{s.t.} &\quad \sum^n_{i=1} x_i^2 = n \\
&\quad x_i \geq 0
\end{align}
$$

Although I believe there could be a a better option to this problem, I was suggest to check for the KKT condition, solving it by Lagrange multipliers. Following this path I've computed the following gradients:

$$
\nabla f(\bar{x}) = \left[ -\frac{1}{x_1^2}, \ldots, - \frac{1}{x^2_n} \right]^T \\
\nabla h(\bar{x}) = 2 \left[x_1, \ldots, x_n\right]^T \\
\nabla g(\bar{x}) = \left[1,\ldots, 1 \right]^T
$$

And writing the first order condition:
$$
\nabla f(\bar{x}) = \lambda \nabla h(\bar{x}) + \mu \nabla g(\bar{x}), \mu \geq 0 \\
\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{x^2_1} \\ \vdots \\ -\frac{1}{x^2_n} \end{bmatrix} = 
2\lambda \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix} +
\mu \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
But I was not able to solve the system of equations. I tried to get some useful relations, like multiplying both sides by the transposed unit vector, summing them:

$$
-\frac{1}{n} = 2\lambda \sum x_i + n \mu
$$

Or trying to evaluate just for a single variable to find some kind of root:

$$
-1 = x^2_i (2\lambda x_i + \mu)
$$
But none of them were fruitful. Any suggestions on how I could proceed or any relations I've missed?

Comment: $\sum_i (-1/x_i^2) \not= -1/\sum_i x_i^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inspection, $\lambda=-1$, $\mu=1$, and $x_i=1$ for all $i$.

Alternatively, suppose $x_i \not= x_j$.  Then replace both $x_i$ and $x_j$ with $\sqrt{\frac{x_i^2+x_j^2}{2}}$.  This change preserves the equality constraint and decreases the objective value (show this).  The conclusion is that all $x_i$ are equal at optimality, which implies that $x_i=1$ for all $i$.